Recreating Sci-Fi background Not having the desired gaps as shown using voronoi
I am recreating this background loop as per Deayan's video:
https://youtu.be/U-BdjGHvfZg
following every Geometry Node but at 6:08 , his background has the desired gaps and mine are without gaps.  What did I miss?
This is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/115aHpVSqnx-pvwHjES3SrPaopjWcCZyw/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance for the help and advice

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ rather than Google Drive which is unlikely to be available for users researching your question in the  future.

Increase the Factor on the Mix Color Multiply node from 0.5 to 1 as he says at 5:54 in his tutorial.


oh... so that's what I missed...   Thank You very much

No problem. Please mark my answer above as correct. Thanks.
